# search line which contains forward slashes

Tags: search

I have a following line in one script:

```
cp "$uploaddir"/"$file" "$cvsdir"/"$device"
```

I would like to search if this exact line is present elsewhere in the script. Usually I would do <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> and then <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. However, this time the line contains forward slashes. I also tried to specify "very nomagic"(`\V`) after the forward slash, but this didn't help. I could obviously do `/cp "$uploaddir"\/"$file" "$cvsdir"\/"$device"`, but this is bit clunky. Is there a better way to search line from text which contains forward slashes without escaping each forward slash?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use backward search `:h ?`. This way you type `?` instead of `/` to start search, but this also allows to use `/` in search pattern.

Comment: This is so simple it's brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the forward slashes, too, not just the backslashes that are the only regular expression pieces requiring escaping when `\V` is used. This can be done with the `escape()` function, and inserting the register via the expression register:

```
y$/<C-r>='\V' . escape(@@, '/\')<CR><CR>
```

There's still an issue with newlines (that's why I used `y$` instead of `yy`), and the expression already is too long to type regularly. And it clobbers a register.

That's why I would recommend to use one of several available **plugin**s that implement such a **literal search of the visual selection**. The [visualstar plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2944) does this, and my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) includes such functionality as well. (The plugin page has links to additional alternative plugins.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -F` to search for literal fixed strings. If you run `grep` from vim, the matching lines are placed in the quickfix list. You can use `:cnext` and `:cprevious` to navigate the results.

```
:gr -F 'cp "$uploaddir"/"$file" "$cvsdir"/"$device"' %
```